# AngularJS Directive Isolated scope inside nested ng-transclude

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-transclude

I've been looking all over the internet for something like this and I still can't find the answer.

I have a directive that is reused throughout my application, it allows the user to sort and search through lists of items. I have multiple kinds of items that can be passed in to the directive (html templates that I pass in) as well as multiple uses for those templates. I.e, sometimes I want a certain button on that template, but sometimes I want another. (This will make more sense in a minute).

Therefore I have created multiple directives with transclusion in order to achieve this. However, I'm having serious issues with scoping and I can't seem to figure out exactly how to pass the isolated scope to the child directive.

Below is my code:

Item List Directive

```
var app = angular.module('main');

app.directive('itemList', function(){
    var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attributes, ctrl, transclude) {
        //Things that modify the scope here. This scope is what I want to pass down to the child directives
        //NOTE: I do not currently have a working transclude function which is why I didn't include it here because I have no idea what to do with it
       scope.pagedItems = groupItemsToPages(items);
       scope.currentPage = 0;
    };

    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       replace: 'true',
       transclude: true,
       templateUrl: 'partials/directives/item-list.html',
       link: linkFunction,
       scope: {
           searchPlaceholder: "@",
           items: "=",
           control: "="
       }
    };
});
```

item-list.html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <!-- I won't put all of the html here, just some to show you what i'm going for -->

     <div class="search-field">
         <input type="text" ng-model="query.value" placeholder="{{searchPlaceholder}}/>
     </div>

     <table class="table table-hover">
         <tbody>
             <tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage]">
                  <td ng-transclude></td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>

</div>
```

Here's the directive that simply returns the URL of whatever template is passed to it. This is so that I can add in an extra html through further nested transclusions.

item-template.js

```
var app = angular.module('main');

app.directive('itemTemplate', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: 'true',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs){
            return tAttrs.templateUrl;
        }
    };
});
```

Here's an example template (extremely simplified again, just to show you the layout)

profile-template.html

```
<div>
    <p>item.name</p>
    <p>item.description</p>
</div>
<div ng-transclude></div>
```

Here's an example of the HTML that calls this code

tab.html

```
<div class="tab">
    <div class="available-items">
        <item-list control="profileControl" search-placeholder="Search Profiles" items="profileControl.profiles">
            <item-template template-url="partials/profile-template.html">
                <button type="button" ng-click="launchProfile(item.id)">Launch Profile</button>
            </item-template>
        </item-list>
    </div>
</div>
```

So now that you've seen the code. The issue I'm having is that my profile-template.html inclusion isn't getting the scope from the directive above it even though I've tried cloning the scope to it. All the examples I've seen require you to remove the template key from the directive and assume you're only returning the code you have in your transclusion. In my case, I have other html that I want to display in the template.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Doesn't the `$parent` property solve your problem?

Comment: I actually feel rather foolish. Yes, that does solve my problem... except for some reason this <img ng-src="{{$parent.retrieveIcon($parent.item.icon)}}"> isn't resolving. I have other methods on the parent scope that resolve just fine... odd

Comment: Instead of `$parent.item.icon`, wouldn't it be something like `$parent.items[i].icon` inside a loop to go through your `$parent.items` list?

Comment: This is already inside of the ng-repeat. Here's the code that's not working: '<div data-original-title="{{$parent.item.name}}" data-toggle="tooltip"> <img ng-src="{{$parent.retrieveIcon($parent.item.iconUrl)}}"></div>' 

For some reason, the retrieveIcon method simply isn't being called.

Comment: And the `data-original-title` parameter is being retrieved correctly?

Comment: It is. I figured it out. The scope gets really out of wack way down there. I had to do a $parent.$parent to get to the method inside of that method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108434/discussion-between-bruno-toffolo-and-the-camino).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to pass the scope between your directives, you can make use of the `$parent` attribute and get access to higher scopes.

For instance, in your `item-template` controller you could gain access to the higher scope from `item-list` with a code like this:

```
if ($parent.searchPlaceholder === '') {
    ...
}
```